# Django admin annotation - Sum fields of related models

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got a django-admin dashboard/listing which attempts to track and summarize "jobs" with an annotated queryset which I think is not working properly. As part of the table, I have displayed calculated fields for data volumes from related objects (as provided by the annotated queryset).

Effectively it's a list of jobs which track work against computer devices and their respective storage devices, so a **Job** can have multiples **Devices** which can have multiple **Storage** devices. Both Devices and Storage can contain data volume (in the same way a phone can have internal memory and a removable memory card.) With some jobs a Device might be naked hard drive or a PC tower with 5 HDD, so I am trying to accommodate these scenarios...

models.py:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    ...
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Device(models.Model):
    ...
    device_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    capacity = models.FloatField(null=True)
    ...

class Storage(models.Model):
    ...
    storage_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    capacity = models.FloatField(null=True)
    ...
```

For the admin model for Job, i've tried the following approach, which *seems* to work, however when I filter (based on a text search against a job name for example) the totals for the data volume shoot up

admin.py

```
class JobAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            _device_count=Count("device", distinct=True),
            _device_volume=Sum("device__capacity", distinct=True)+Sum("device__storage__capacity", distinct=True)
           )
        return queryset

    def data_label(self,obj):
        return obj._device_volume
```

I've noticed that if I search/filter against a job name and get multiple hits, it appears to multiply the data sum by the number of results, but if I filter on some other field (using list_filter fields) it doesn't occur.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I appreciate any advice.

Han

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to combine multiple **aggregations** with **annotate()** because [this will yield the wrong results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) (since joins are used instead of **subqueries**)

So how to do it? Use [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), something along the lines should do the job:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Sum, Count


def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
        _device_count=Subquery(
            Device.objects.filter(job=OuterRef("pk"))
            .values("job")
            .annotate(cnt=Count("id"))
            .values("cnt")
        ),
        _device_capacity=Subquery(
            Device.objects.filter(job=OuterRef("pk"))
            .values("job")
            .annotate(vol=Sum("capacity"))
            .values("vol")
        ),
        _storage_capacity=Subquery(
            Storage.objects.filter(device__job=OuterRef("pk"))
            .values("device__job")
            .annotate(vol=Sum("capacity"))
            .values("vol")
        ),
    )
    return queryset
```

You could try to make one more annotation in order to get the sum of `_device_capacity` and `_storage_capacity`, but I guess it would be easy enough to sum it inside python, so maybe no need to bother the database.

Comment: Wow, thanks mate. It's so useful to see the concepts demonstrated against a specific, relatable example. I'm a django nuffy, so I imagine I will learn a lot from picking this apart and going through the docs. BTW it works perfectly!

Comment: I can see how I can sum these as part of a function, outside the query set, but just out of interest, how would I combine these within the queryset?

Comment: It should be something like: `.annotate(_total_capacity=F('_device_capacity') + F('_storage_capacity'))`, but you may also need to wrap this in an [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations)